# Returning int data type v/s passing a reference

Tags: c++, return

To count the number of nodes in a binary tree during a level order traversal. Having a bit of an issue of returning the number of nodes via the function , so is there an alternative to keep count?

```
void Level_Order(node* root,int& n){
queue<node *> q;
if(root){
    q.push(root);
    n++;
}
while(!q.empty()){
    node* temp = q.front();
    q.pop();
    if(temp->left){
        push temp->left
        n++;
    }
    if(temp->right){
        push temp->right
        n++;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: `void` means it doesn't return anything. So you need to change the return type, and then add a `return` statement that returns the value.

Comment: Well you could make the return type not be void, or you could take an additional pointer/reference for the result location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the return type from `void` to `int`, you should then change the parameter type of n:

```
void Level_Order(node* root,int& n){
```

the `n` is now a [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm), and the original variable will be modified through this reference.

```
node root = getRoot();
int nNode = 0;

Level_Order(&root, nNode);
printf("Number of nodes is : %d\n", nNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type specifies what, if any, type of data a function (method) returns. `void` indicates there is no return type.

If you want the function to return an integer, then you'll need to change the return type to `int`. It's pretty straight forward so I'm not sure where you're getting hung up.

As others have pointed out, it's also possible to accept a reference or pointer argument and get the updated value back to the caller. But generally return type refers to the function return type, and it'll need to match what you want it to return.